# Any travel insurances covering canceled flights/trains before the day of departure?

Tags: usa, air-travel, trains, cancellations, insurance

Suppose we're dealing with the following scenarios (that actually happened to me):

- Being in the middle of a trip in the US, Amtrak canceled the train that I was supposed to take 10 days before the scheduled departure date, due to wildfires. So I had to book an overpriced flight just 10 days before the departure date and spend an extra night (that I was planning to spend on the train) in a hotel.
- Being in the middle of a trip in the US, an airline cancels the flight one day before the departure without rescheduling, and the next flight is only in 3 days. So I had to spend 3 more nights in a hotel.

Are there any travel insurances that would have covered those additional expenses (i.e., extra night(s) in a hotel/hostel, and a flight in the first case)? I only had CSR travel insurance when this happened, but I believe it doesn't cover any of the above.

Comment: A wildfire would be a force majeure and I'd be shocked if you'd find insurance covering it.

Comment: Why is it a shock to find an insurance covering such disasters? Isn't the purpose of insurance to protect us from losses arising from unavoidable disasters?